# update d3 in browser from python

Tags: python, sockets, d3.js, websocket

I'd like to be constantly updating a d3.js visualization from a python script running on a server so the user in the browser sees the realtime changes.

How can I do this? I assume some usage of websockets with a socket on the python end, but are there any libraries or projects specialized for this purpose I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSockets would definitely seem a good fit for your requirement.

Regarding WebSocket and python, there is possibly some overlap with this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839054/websocket-server-in-python/5839223#5839223

There is a WebSocket implementation in **Tornado**:

http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/